# ¿Como aplicar LIMIT a un GROUP_CONCAT que está en medio de una query?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, concat

tengo un pequeño problema que he intentado resolver por todos los medios, sin embargo he fracasado al intentar hacer algo que para alguno de ustedes puede ser sencillo. La situacion es:
Tengo una consulta que me funciona medianamente bien, lo que no logro es obtener un LIMIT adentro del GROUP_CONCAT, es decir, si la query me devuelve 5 datos en un concat, necesito que solo me devuelva 3. La query es la siguiente:

```
SELECT c.id_cli, c.nombre, l.lect_act, l.lect_ant, l.dife, l.precio,b.debe, b.saldoacum as SALDOACUMULADO, b.debe+b.saldoacum as TOTAL,
b.debe+b.saldoacum+0.57 as APAGAR,GROUP_CONCAT(l.dife SEPARATOR '-') as diferencia1,GROUP_CONCAT(l.precio SEPARATOR '-') as precio1 from clientes c INNER JOIN cobro b on b.id_cli='01SG0001' INNER JOIN
 lectura l on l.id_cli=c.id_cli WHERE b.id_cob in( SELECT MAX(id_cob) from cobro d where d.id_cli='01SG0001' and
 d.saldoacum >=0) and l.id_lect in (SELECT DISTINCT id_lect from lectura x where x.id_cli='01SG0001') and
 c.estado='ACTIVO'
```

La query me devuelve los datos que solicito, mas no , el limite. Si alguien puediera darme una mano, estaria mas que agradecido! Muchas gracias por el compartir su conocimiento con todos nosotros! Saludos!

Comment: Puedes hacer algo mediante el uso de `substring_index`, ver por ejemplo [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23608554/5587982). Pero yo, cuando veo que hay que recurrir a cosas tan estrambóticas para obtener unos resultados me pregunto si tu modelo de datos no necesita ser revisado con urgencia. ¿Por qué tienes que escribir una consulta tan extraña, en la que haya que aplicar un límite dentro de `GROUP_CONCAT`, usando además en ella `MAX`, `SELECT DISTINCT`, etc, etc. ¿?

Comment: Es por el tipo de procesos que la empresa tiene, es una facturación muy extraña la que tienen en la que neesitan los ultimos registros del cliente, mas el resumen de las ultimas 3 facturas con datos en varias tablas distintas. Sé que es un poco extraña esa consulta, sin embargo me es funcional, he probrado con el substrign y no me ha dado resultado. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He logrado resolver! Muchas gracias a todos!
Saludos!

```
SELECT c.id_cli, c.nombre, l.lect_act, l.lect_ant, l.dife, l.precio,b.debe, b.saldoacum as SALDOACUMULADO, 
b.debe+b.saldoacum as TOTAL, b.debe+b.saldoacum+0.57 as APAGAR,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(l.dife  ORDER BY l.dife DESC SEPARATOR '-'),"-",3) as diferencia1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(l.precio ORDER BY l.precio DESC SEPARATOR '-'),"-",3) as precio1
from clientes c INNER JOIN cobro b on b.id_cli='01SG0001' INNER JOIN lectura l 
on l.id_cli=c.id_cli WHERE b.id_cob in( SELECT MAX(id_cob) from cobro d 
where d.id_cli='01SG0001' and d.saldoacum >=0) 
and l.id_lect in (SELECT id_lect from lectura x where x.id_cli='01SG0001')
 and c.id_cli='01SG0001'
```